# Passing [H] with the float package isn't working

Tags: floats, apa6

My LaTeX was similar to:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\affiliation{UNIVERSITY}
\subtitle{SUBTITLE}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{SECTION A}
Paragraph text.

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{IMAGE.png}
\caption{INFORMATION OF FIGURE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've tried passing different options through `\includegraphics` such as `[scale=0.2]`. I've tried `[!H]`. I've tried `\vspace{-20pt}` in the figure tag. I can't get the image to not appear on the next page. I've tried almost everything and couldn't find anything online about it (if you somehow find it... how?). I'm using TeXStudio on Windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure there's enough vertical space remaining on the current page to put the float there?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. There are two sentences at the top of the page. Moreover, when I use the lipsum package and generate dummy text, even with passing [H], the image is on the last page. It doesn't matter even if I scale it [scale=0.1]. Help?

Comment: document class `apa6` doesn't allow to have image on the first page.

Comment: The images are not on the first page / title page. It's about 4 pages in. I could post the whole thing if you want, but it's a little lengthy.

Comment: Here is the whole report: https://pastebin.com/txnHnvJh

Comment: i meant on the first document text page (not cover page). see my answer below.

Comment: The image is also not on the first document page; it is about 4 pages in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit:**

option `man` of the document class `apa6` doesn't allow floats in document. figures must be delivered separately. if you will delete this option, document will have text in  two columns with image on the place where it is inseted (without use of `H` placement option).

if you still persist to break rules of this document class, than don't use `float` environment and for caption use `captionof` macro:

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{float}   % not used
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{capt-of}   % new

\title{TITLE}
\author{AUTHOR}
\affiliation{UNIVERSITY}
%\subtitle{SUBTITLE}  % it is not defined

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{SECTION A}
Paragraph text.

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{INFORMATION OF FIGURE}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although this doesn't directly solve the issue of float [H] option not working, I truly appreciate the effort and at any rate, this is a work around. Thank you for taking the time to write this up for me, Zarko! Much appreciated. I'll mark this as an answer. Even though I'll mark it, if you can solve this via float or otherwise (don't have to), I'd much appreciate it. Thanks ~

Comment: @ZackaryCW, see edited answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I just saw your edit that floats are not used in [man] option of apa6. Thanks for the help, Zarko and rest.